# Showing error output in Jtextarea using netbeans

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea

I am creating a  small application like calculator. I have jTextField,jTextArea and a Jbutton. When I type  *121* and then button click ***I want to get the answer as 4*** in Jtextarea. But when I click *I am getting wrong answer as 242.*

Following is my code:

```
 private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        int va=Integer.parseInt( jTextField1.getText());
       int  vb= Integer.parseInt(jTextField1.getText());
      int ca= va+vb;
      jTextArea1.append(Integer.toString(ca));
      jTextArea1.append("\n");
    }
```

Comment: You're getting text from the same field twice, so `121+121` is `242`...

Comment: @MadProgrammer But I want to get the answer as 1+2+1=4

Comment: Then you need to break the `String` down...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting text from the same field twice, so `121+121` is `242`...

> But I want to get the answer as 1+2+1=4

Then you need to take each character in the `String` and add them together, for example...

```
    String text = "121";
    int result = 0;
    for (char c : text.toCharArray()) {
        result += Integer.parseInt(Character.toString(c));
    }

    System.out.println(result);
```

Which prints `4`